# Uploading to EAS Build : Error: Request failed: 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

When I want to Build the apk output for the expo project
by this :

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

gives this error:

```
✖ Uploading to EAS Build (1.8 MB / 1.8 MB)
     Error: Request failed: 403 (Forbidden)
```

I followed the steps through the site's own documentation.

https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/

my eas.json

```
{
    "build": {
      "preview": {
        "android": {
          "buildType": "apk"
        }
      },
      "preview2": {
        "android": {
          "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
        }
      },
      "preview3": {
        "developmentClient": true
      },
      "production": {}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed my dns using [shecan](https://shecan.ir/) and it worked.

Comment: ممنون، مشکل با تغییر DNS یا استفاده از قندشکن حل میشه

Comment: I really  thank you for the only solution , you saved me . @pedram