# eas build failed to upload the project tarball with 403 error - expo

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm trying to build the project for hours and always the same error

```
Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/eas-build-archive
✖ Uploading to EAS Build (817 KB / 817 KB)       
Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build

Reason: Request failed: 403 (Forbidden)
    Error: build command failed.
```

the steps to build :

1_  install git

2_ npm install -g eas-cli

3_ npx expo install expo-dev-client

4_ eas build:configure

5_ the **eas.json** auto-generated and sounds like

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

6_ expo-dev-client installed as a dependency

**the commands i've tried**

```
**eas build --platform android**

**eas build --platform all**

**eas build --profile development --platform android**
```

**and all end up with the same error **

and **app.json** have my correct projectId

```
"extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxx"
      }
    }
```

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it , the only solution is to select DNS manually.
steps on windows :
1_ go control panel

2_ network and sharing center

3_ change adapter setting

4_ click right on your connection (Wi-Fi or local)

5_ properties => IPv4 => properties => use the following DNS server address

=> preferred DNS server : copy this : **178.22.122.100**

alternate DNS server : copy this :  **185.51.200.2**

6_ Select Validate settings upon exit.

7_ Press the OK button and close the window.

source :https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160678/16367515